# Volume of n dimensional ball

Tags: calculus

- The open ball of radius $r$ in  $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ is the set
  $\left\{\left(x_{1}, x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\right)\in \mathbb{R}^{N} \mid \sum_{i = 1}^{N} x_{i}^{2} < r^{2}\right\}$.
- By definition its volume $V_N\left(r\right) =
  \int\int\cdots\int 1\,\,{\rm d}x_{1}\,{\rm d}x_{2}\ldots
  {\rm d}x_{N}$

$$
\mbox{How to prove that}\quad 
V_{N} = V_{N - 1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{n}\left(\theta\right)
\,{\rm d}\theta\,\,\, ?
$$

$V_{n}$ is the volume of the $n$-dimensional unit ball.

Any idea how I can show this please. I have no idea what sort of approach I should take.

Comment: Your MathJax style is quite uninformed.  You shouldn't keep alternating in and out of MathJax in the middle of one block of math notation.  See my edits.  One doesn't put "=" _outside_ of MathJax while the things on either side of it are in MathJax, and lots of other things like that appeared.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#Recursions). There is a recursion that is similar to yours on the page. It should be easy to show equivalence of the terms.

Answer (score 5):

Search:

"Finding Volume and Surface Area of Hyperspheres in ${\Bbb R}^n$" (Mario Sracic)

"The volume of a n-dimensional hypersphere" (A. E. Lawrence)

"The volume of a n-dimensional sphere in ${\Bbb R}^{n+1}$"

Answer (score 4):

$$
V_n(r) = \int_0^r \int_{x_1^2+\cdots+x_{n-1}^2\le r^2-x^2} dx_1\ldots dx_{n-1} dx
\\ = \int_0^r  V_{n-1}(\sqrt{r^2-x^2}) dx\\
= \int_0^{\frac\pi 2}  V_{n-1}(r\cos\theta) r\cos\theta \ \ d\theta
$$

Now use the fact that $V_n(r) = r^n V_n(1) =: r^n V_n$:
$$
r^n V_n 
= \int_0^{\frac\pi 2}  V_{n-1}(r\cos\theta)^{n-1} r\cos\theta \ \ d\theta\\
V_n 
= V_{n-1}\int_0^{\frac\pi 2}  (\cos\theta)^{n}\ d\theta
$$

Comment: How is the first line only limited to 2 integrals because we are integrating over n dimensions. Also how to obtain line 2

Comment: The interior integral is $(n-1)$-dimensional and ${x_1^2+\cdots+x_{n-1}^2\le r^2-x^2}$ is a $n-1$ dimensional ball of radius $\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla could you explain why the most outer integral ranges from $0$ to $r$ and not from $-r$ to $r$?

Comment: @Richard There is no explanation, because (as you suspected) the integral is wrong. Integrating from $-r$ to $r$ would fix it.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, you **cannot** prove that

$$ V_n \stackrel?= V_{n-1} \int _0 ^{\pi/2} \cos^n \theta \, \mathrm d\theta.$$

The two sides of this alleged "equation" are not equal.

For example, let $n = 3.$ Then $V_{n-1} = V_2 = \pi$
and

$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^n \theta \, \mathrm d\theta
= \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^3 \theta \, \mathrm d\theta = \frac23.
$$

Hence
$$
V_{n-1} \int _0 ^{\pi/2} \cos^n \theta \, \mathrm d\theta = \frac23\pi.
$$

But
$$
V_n = V_3 = \frac43\pi.
$$

To correct the equation, we can either integrate from $-\frac\pi2$ to $\frac\pi2$ instead of $0$ to $\frac\pi2$
(equivalent to integrating in Cartesian coordinates from $-r$ to $r$ instead of from $0$ to $r$, as suggested in a comment under
[another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/711102/139123))
or we can recognize the symmetry of that integral and simply double the original integral. That is,

$$
V_n = V_{n-1} \int _{-\pi/2} ^{\pi/2} \cos^n \theta \, \mathrm d\theta
=  2 V_{n-1} \int _0 ^{\pi/2} \cos^n \theta \, \mathrm d\theta.
$$

---

A correct derivation in the style of
[the answer mentioned above](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/711102/139123)
could be
\begin{align}
V_n
&= \int_{x_1^2+\cdots+x_{n-1}^2+x_n^2\leq 1}
      \mathrm dx_1 \cdots \mathrm dx_{n-1}\, \mathrm dx_n \\
&= \int_{x_n^2\leq 1} \int_{x_1^2+\cdots+x_{n-1}^2\le 1-x^2}
      \mathrm dx_1\cdots \mathrm dx_{n-1}\, \mathrm dx_n \\
&= \int_{-1}^1 \left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)^{n-1} V_{n-1}\, \mathrm dx \\
&= \int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2} (\cos^{n-1}\theta) V_{n-1}\cdot \cos\theta
      \,\mathrm d\theta \\
&= V_{n-1} \int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2} \cos^n\theta \,\mathrm d\theta
\end{align}

using the notational convention that the volume of an $n$-ball of radius $r$ is $r^n V_n.$