# Calculate the Volume of the unitary n-ball

Tags: integration, volume

To do this first I need to prove that :

$$\displaystyle \int_R \sin^{n-2}\phi_1 \sin^{n-3}\phi_2\cdots\sin \phi_{n-2} d\theta d\phi_1 \cdots d\phi_{n-2} = \frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}$$

where $ R=[0,2\pi] \times [0,\pi]^{n-2}$ but here there is a hint: Calculate the integral $\int_{\mathbb R^n}e^{-|x|^2}dx$ in spherical coordinates but this integral is a very complicated one, and from there I have found the following http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#Direct_integration_in_spherical_coordinates
but How to do this without the betha function? so what Can be done with these two problems? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-|x|^2} dx = \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx\right)^n$$ and I'm sure you know how to calculate the RHS for the special case $n = 2$.

Comment: Yes that is right ;), but then ...

Comment: You can also do this with induction on the dimension of the sphere (basis cases $n=1$ and $n=2$).

Comment: An how do that help in the calculation?, I want to calculate that integral in spherical coordinates, so I will have the jacobian and all that stuff, I have allready prove that the above integral is $\pi ^{n/2}$ but in spherical coordinates it is compkicated

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711082/volume-of-n-dimensional-ball and http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~karigian/teaching/multivariable-calculus/hypersphere.pdf for alternative ideas.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) but I think my case is very diferent

Comment: Let me check it :) if I have a doubt can I let  you know ?

Comment: "How to do this without the betha function?" Try to find a recurrence formula for the integrals.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [recurrence formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795037/integral-of-sinnx-recurrence-relation-some-properties)

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^n(x)dx = \frac{n-1}n\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n-2}(x)dx.
$$